# Accessing std::vector methods inside std::optional

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdoptional

I have got an Element, which is a std::vector in a std::optional.
Now I want to emplace an Element to the vector (via emplace_back):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>

int main()
{
    std::optional<std::vector<uint8_t>> optvec;
    optvec->reserve(1);

    optvec->emplace_back(1);

    std::cout << optvec.has_value() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, regarding the memory, this emplaces the element itself correctly, but the optional part doesn't get it that there is an element, so it's a nullopt.

Is there another way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

When you do

```
std::optional<std::vector<uint8_t>> optvec;
optvec->reserve(1);
```

your program has undefined behaviour, in much the same way as if you had done

```
std::vector<uint8_t> * optvec{ nullptr };
optvec->reserve(1);
```

Why do you want an optional vector in the first place? A vector can already hold zero elements.

> Is there another way to do this?

Have a (potentially empty) plain vector.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> optvec;
```

Comment: i need this because i've got a much bigger structure holding different types, and all Elements which aren't always present are defined as optional, so the vectors too. But thanks, good hint, maybe it's avoidable.

Answer (score 3):

Your `optional` does not contain any vector.
The default constructor of [optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) builds it an object that does not contain any value.

You can simply

```cpp
std::optional<std::vector<uint8_t>> optvec = std::vector<uint8_t>();
```

or...

```cpp
std::optional<std::vector<uint8_t>> optvec;
optvec.emplace();
```

and then you have an actual vector in your `optional`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way to do this?

Yes, give the `optional` a value

```
int main()
{
  std::optional<std::vector<uint8_t>> optvec;
  assert(!optvec.has_value());

  optvec = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
  assert(optvec.has_value());

  optvec.value().emplace_back('d');
}
```